# C++ Errors in Eclipse

Tags: c++

I have written this header file in Eclipse. Eclipse is showing errors that I am not sure what they mean. The code:

is >> numPairs;
kP = new KeyValuePair[numPairs];

Eclipse shows numPairs and kP are not resolved. Then the last two methods (createTable and getValue) shows "Invalid Overload". I asked my TA about this today and he said the code was correct. I have also tried separating it into an implementation file, but the same errors persist. My header files are in the src folder as well as main.cpp. Is there something I am missing?

```
#ifndef TRANSLATIONTABLE_H_
#define TRANSLATIONTABLE_H_
#include "KeyValuePair.h"

template<typename Key, typename Value>
class TranslationTable
{
private:
    int numPairs;
    KeyValuePair<Key,Value> *kP;

public:
    TranslationTable(std::istream& is);
    TranslationTable();
    void createTable(std::istream& is);
    Value getValue(Key myKey) const;
};

 template<typename Key, typename Value>
 TranslationTable<typename Key,typename Value>TranslationTable()
 {return;}

 template<typename Key, typename Value>
 TranslationTable<typename Key,typename Value>TranslationTable(std::istream& is)
 {
is >> numPairs;
kP = new KeyValuePair<Key,Value>[numPairs];
 }

 template<typename Key, typename Value>
 void TranslationTable<Key,Value>::createTable(std::istream& is)
 {
is >> numPairs;
kP = new KeyValuePair<Key,Value>[numPairs];
 }

 template<typename Key, typename Value>
 Value TranslationTable<Key,Value>::getValue(Key myKey) const
 {

}

#endif /* TRANSLATIONTABLE_H_ */
```

Comment: Your constructor definitions (the signatures) look strange. Where's the `::`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot scope resolution notation `::` for constructor definition:

```
 template<typename Key, typename Value>
 TranslationTable<typename Key,typename Value>::TranslationTable()
                                              ^^^

 template<typename Key, typename Value>
 TranslationTable<typename Key,typename Value>::TranslationTable(std::istream& is)
                                              ^^^
```